# Is it easy to move to Singapore as a UK citizen for a career in programming/business?

Tags: working-visas, uk-citizens, singapore, career

Looking to migrate or looking for experience to start a new life.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it's not easy.** You basically need a firm job offer & visa sponsorship from a Singaporean company to be able to get a work visa, and it's a long and uncertain path from there to permanent residence.

Comment: I found no problem in moving there as a programmer. In 6 months I was a PR and after two years they offered me citizenship. Try Job Street Asia, Jobs DB and Monster